# Why is the @media screen CSS not working?

Tags: html, css

I want to make some changes to the website on devices with the minimum width of 1024px but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Moshify Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <h3>Heading 3</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus earum
      architecto veritatis dignissimos cum, vitae cupiditate accusamus facilis!
      Est, distinctio.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

:root {
  --color-primary: #2584ff;
  --color-secondary: #00d9ff;
  --color-accent: #ff3400;
  --color-headings: #1b0760;
  --color-body: #918ca4;
}

body {
  font-family: Inter, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: var(--color-body);
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: var(--color-headings);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 7rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }


  h1 {
    font-size: 8rem;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }

   

  h3 {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your HTML. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Please also don't abuse the site rules by posting filler text to circumvent post length requirements. Use real words to describe your problem and what you've tried to solve it, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have imported your CSS file to your html file or not? That could be a reason.
else you can try adding only as follows:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
}
```